# Placing Line Breaks in an Ordered List

Tags: html, xhtml

On a line in an ordered list I have a graphic link and then text next to the graphic. I would like to have the text go underneath the graphic opposed to next to it.

Here is my code:

```
 <ol id="resources">
       <li><a href="http://trbc.org" target="_blank"><img src="images/trbc.png" alt="Thomas Road Baptist Road Chruch"></a>Thomas Road Baptist Church</li>
       <li><a href="http://www.redeemerlynchburg.org/wp/" target="_blank"><img src="images/redeemerLogo.png" alt="Redeemer Presbyterian Chruch"></a>Redeemer Presbyterian Church</li>
       <li><a href="http://www.onecc.org/" target="_blank"><img src="images/oneLogo.png" alt="One Community Chruch"></a>One Community Church</li>
       <li><a href="http://rgbaptist.org/" target="_blank"><img src="images/graceLogo.png" alt="Redeeming Grace Church"></a> Redeeming Grace Church</li>
       <li><a href="http://www.hbclynchburg.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/heritageLogo.png" alt="Heritage Baptist Church"></a>Heritage Baptist Church</li>
 </ol>
```

Is there anyone who has a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<ol id="resources">
       <li>
         <a href="http://trbc.org" target="_blank">
           <img src="images/trbc.png" alt="Thomas Road Baptist Road Chruch"></a>
  </br>
Thomas Road Baptist Church</li>
       <li><a href="http://www.redeemerlynchburg.org/wp/" target="_blank"><img src="images/redeemerLogo.png" alt="Redeemer Presbyterian Chruch"></a>
  </br>
Redeemer Presbyterian Church</li>
       <li><a href="http://www.onecc.org/" target="_blank"><img src="images/oneLogo.png" alt="One Community Chruch"></a>
  </br>
One Community Church</li>
       <li><a href="http://rgbaptist.org/" target="_blank"><img src="images/graceLogo.png" alt="Redeeming Grace Church"></a> </br>
Redeeming Grace Church</li>
       <li><a href="http://www.hbclynchburg.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/heritageLogo.png" alt="Heritage Baptist Church"></a>
  </br>
Heritage Baptist Church</li>
 </ol>
```

You're good man, you just need to write your break element 
as a self-ending element with the slash in the element as above.

Comment: I tried that; however, the <br> in a list will not validate.

Comment: Did you try it with a forward slash within the break element exactly as shown above? You're displaying your break element incorrectly without a self-ending forward slash.  It would not validate to semantically correct html the way you're displaying it. I.E. the snippet provided won't execute a "break" without the forward slash prior to the break element.

Comment: Why are you writing `</br>` instead of `<br/>`?

Answer (score 2):

the br tag, while convenient in this case, is not semantically corrent, nor very flexible when you start getting into responsive design

http://html5doctor.com/element-index/#br

a better solution would be to use CSS and make the link push the content below itself.

https://jsfiddle.net/3spthgs2/

```
#resources a{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

display:table-cell is used because display:block would make the link take up the full width of it's parent and the whitespace would be clickable

Comment: I agree in not using breaks where not needed as they do play all sorts of games with your responsive layouts later down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Road Baptist Church

Redeemer Presbyterian Church

One Community Church

Redeeming Grace Church

Heritage Baptist Chu

```html
 <ol id="resources">
       <li><a href="http://trbc.org" target="_blank"><img src="images/trbc.png" alt="Thomas Road Baptist Road Chruch"></a>
<div style="clear:both"></div>Thomas Road Baptist Church</li>
       <li><a href="http://www.redeemerlynchburg.org/wp/" target="_blank"><img src="images/redeemerLogo.png" alt="Redeemer Presbyterian Chruch"></a><div style="clear:both"></div>Redeemer Presbyterian Church</li>
       <li><a href="http://www.onecc.org/" target="_blank"><img src="images/oneLogo.png" alt="One Community Chruch"></a><div style="clear:both"></div>One Community Church</li>
       <li><a href="http://rgbaptist.org/" target="_blank"><img src="images/graceLogo.png" alt="Redeeming Grace Church"></a><div style="clear:both"></div>Redeeming Grace Church</li>
       <li><a href="http://www.hbclynchburg.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/heritageLogo.png" alt="Heritage Baptist Church"></a><div style="clear:both"></div>Heritage Baptist Church</li>
 </ol>
```

Alternatively, you could try popping in a DIV tag with a clear both style as shown above.

Comment: <li><a href="http://rgbaptist.org/" target="_blank"><img src="images/graceLogo.png" alt="Redeeming Grace Church"></a><span style="clear:both">Redeeming Grace Church</span></li>  <!-- you could use the above method within a span on the text as well as shown for one list item here if you have trouble with your styles due to the span being in a separate div tag. -->

Answer (score 0):

After adding the break between the image and the text, you can also move the images relative to the text by adding this to the image:

```
    style="float:left; margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px"
```

Your image code would look like this:

```
    <img src="images/trbc.png" alt="Thomas Road Baptist Road Chruch" style="float:left; margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px" />
```

Depending on where the text and the image is located on the page, you may need to float:right instead of float:left. The order for manipulating the space around the image for the margin is counter-clockwise and is top, right, bottom, left. The break will move the text beneath the picture but needs additional instructions in order to be positioned relative to the text. Without knowing the actual size of the image relative to the text beneath it, it is hard to provide recommendations for the spacing necessary.

I hope this provides you with another option for controlling the image.